# SSRS make aggregation on both row and column scope

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset like this:

```
RowGrp1 RowGrp2    Col     Value
---------------------------------------
1       1          A       1
1       2          B       2
2       1          A       3
2       2          B       4
```

When designing SSRS matrix, I've set `RowGrp1` and `RowGrp2` into row groups and `Col` into column group. In the data zone I write my expression to calculate `SUM(value)` within row group 1, as `=Sum(Fields!Value.value, "RowGrp1")`.

I found my column group was not effective when applying this calculation. The result of my matrix is as below:

```
RowGrps  A     B    
-----------------
1  1     3     3
   2     3     3
2  1     7     7
   2     7     7
```

How can I make my value still grouped by column group while I have to use scope in my expression (for unmentioned purposed here)?

Answer (score -2):

Remove the scope from the expression, just use

```
=Sum(Fields!Value.value)
```

By setting the scope you are telling SSRS to sum at that specific scope. By omitting the scope you are telling SSRS to sum at the scope of the 'cell'.

Comment: Scope is intend not to be removed, because I want to show the sum of value over `rowGroup1` in the cells. In other words, I want to group by value over both `rowGourp1` and `Col`, but not `rowGroup2`